# How about or what about?

Tags: questions

> They discovered that he couldn't read?

If I change this sentence into question,

> 1. How did they discover about him?
> 2. What did they discover about him?

Which question word should I use? I think ''what about'' and ''how about'' are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they both work, of course. However, out of your two examples, the first one is just not good English.

> How did they discover **that** about him?
>   What did they discover about him?

Did you know that **how** is actually an adverb? Adverbs are words that describe verbs. I think it's an adverb of manner, actually. Those are the adverbs that tell you something about the manner an action is done. So, in the first example, you want to know in what manner they obtained that information about him. In other words, you want to know how they did that. In the second example, on the other hand, you want them to tell you the actual information that was discovered about him.